# Object declaration in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, object, declaration

Is there any difference in declaring objects in Objective-C between (1) and (2), besides the style and personal preference?

**(1) One-line declaration, allocation, initialization.**

`Student *myStudent = [[Student alloc] init];`

**(2) Multi-line declaration, allocation, initialization.**

```
Student *myStudent;
myStudent = [Student alloc]; 
myStudent = [myStudent init];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second case, you can initialize the same object more than once. You send an `alloc` message to the class to get an uninitialized instance, that you must then initialize, having several ways to do it:

```
NSString *myStr = [NSString alloc];
NSString *str1 = [myStr init]; //Empty string
NSString *str2 = [myStr initWithFormat:@"%@.%@", parentKeyPath, key];
```

Comment: what are you trying to do here? `myStr`, `str1` and `str2` will all point to the same string object, ie only the last initialization is relevant

Comment: I agree with christoph, not only that, but if you made any changes to the internal structure of str1 that are not overwritten by initWith format: between init and initWithFormat: those changes will still be there.

Comment: No, you can't do that. I mean, you can write it, but it's **totally wrong**. Also, whether `myStr`, `str1` and `str2` point to the same string is implementation-dependent. In most implementations, they will be different objects when you do this with NSString or any other class cluster, but will be the same object for other classes.

Answer (score 4):

No, there isn't a difference. The [Student alloc] just allocates memory for a pointer, meanwhile [myStudent init] actually sets the initial values.

If you are familiar with C, think of alloc as doing

```
Student *myStudent = calloc(1, sizeof(Student));
```

And the init call as a function that sets the initial values.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, no difference.